# why is the fork() function in my code not creating a child process?

Tags: c, fork, pid, child-process

I am trying to write a program that takes command line arguments to verify a  date and then show all files modified after that date. For some reason, the fork() function does not seem to be creating a child process and does not execute the corresponding part of code, and I can't figure out why. any suggestions?

The fork() parts themselves are on lines 59 and 76. The rest of the code runs fine, but the findafterdate() function only executes for the parent process.

```
 1 #define _XOPEN_SOURCE
 2 #include <stdio.h>
 3 #include <stdlib.h>
 4 #include <string.h>
 5 #include <time.h>
 6 #include <sys/wait.h>
 7 #include <unistd.h>
 8 #include <sys/types.h>
 9 #include <sys/stat.h>
10 #include <pthread.h>
11 char date[255];
12 char startLoc[255];
13
14
15 int findafterdate(int pid, char startLocation);
16
17
18
19 int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
20     //check arguments have been used
21
22     if(argc <2){
23         fprintf(stderr, "ERROR -- no argument set. use -h for help\n");
24         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
25     }
26
27     //check for help switch
28     if (strcmp(argv[1], "-h")==0){
29         printf("usage: %s -t \"YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss\"\n", argv[0]);
30         exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
31     }
32     //check for cutoff time switch
33     else if(strcmp(argv[1], "-t")==0){
34       //check correct argument was used
35       if (argc <= 2){
36          fprintf(stderr, "ERROR -- use the format: %s -t \"YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss\"\n", argv[0]);
37          exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
38       }
39       //set global variable startLoc to argv[3], or "." if none has been given
40       if (argc <= 3){
41         printf("test");
42         strncpy(startLoc, ".", sizeof(startLoc));
43         printf("start location automatically set to launch directory\n");
44       }
45       else{
46         printf("test");
47         strncpy(startLoc, argv[3], sizeof(startLoc));
48         printf("start location set to %s\n", startLoc);
49       }
50       //check if a filename was given
51
52       if ((strncmp(argv[2], "2", 1)!=0)){
53         printf("filename identified\n");
54         struct stat filestat;
55         stat(("%s", argv[2]), &filestat);
56         printf("%s", ctime(&filestat.st_mtime));
57         strncpy(date, ("%s", ctime(&filestat.st_mtime)), sizeof(date));
58         pid_t pid;
59         pid = fork();
60         findafterdate(pid, *startLoc);
61         return 0;
62       }
63
64       //check length of string to determine whether correct YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss format was used
65       else if (strlen(argv[2]) <16 || strlen(argv[2])>19){
66         fprintf(stderr, "ERROR -- Invalid date format\n");
67         exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
68       }
69       //re - format argument into tm
70       struct tm tm;
71
72       memset(&tm, 0, sizeof(struct tm));
73       strptime(argv[2], "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", &tm);
74       strftime(date, sizeof(date), "%b %d %Y %H:%M", &tm);
75       pid_t pid;
76       pid = fork();
77       findafterdate(pid, *startLoc);
78       return 0;
79     }
80 }
81 int findafterdate(int pid, char startLocation){
82     if (pid==0){
83 //      printf("child check");
84         printf("start location: %s || date : %s\n", startLocation, date);
85         execl("/usr/bin/find", "find",("%s", startLocation), "-newermt", ("%s", date), NULL);
86     }
87     else{
88         printf("listing files modified after: %s\n", date);
89         int status;
90         waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
91     }
92     return EXIT_SUCCESS;
93   }
                                                                                                                                                                                             62,2-5        Bot
```

The child process should print "child check" (this was added to ensure it wasn't seg faulting during the actual process) before executing "find  -newermt " to show all the files under the starting directory that were modified after the date given. Instead, it simply does nothing. I cannot for the life of me figure out why this is.

Comment: What does `fork()` return then?  You never check for any errors.

Comment: Try adding a `fflush(stdout);` before the `execl()`. Also check for errors from the latter function. And what is that ("%s", blah) stuff in it supposed to be doing? Do you really want to be using the comma operator?

Comment: When you present source code, *please* do not include line numbers.  The line numbers defeat half the purpose of including the code, by making it hard for us to work with it ourselves.  If you want to call our attention to a particular line or lines then there are better ways to do it, such as by inserting for-purpose comments.

Comment: @Shawn i'll try checking for errors, though i dont think that's the issue as the `fork()` doesn't seem to be creating a child process at all. as for the `("%s" , blah)` stuff, I'm a student and very new to C, and that's the only way I've figured out how to use strings in arguments so far. If you could show me a better way that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: In `findafterdate()`, `startLocation` is a `char` but is passed to `printf()` as an argument corresponding to a `%s` format descriptor, where a `char *` is expected. The compiler should have warned you about this; try compiling with warnings turned on. As a consequence, the behavior of the program is undefined.

Comment: You are passing a `char` as an argument to `execl` rather than a `char *`.  Turn up the compiler warnings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `findafterdate()`, `startLocation` is a `char` but is passed to `printf()` as an argument corresponding to a `%s` format descriptor, where a `char *` is expected. The compiler should have warned you about this; try compiling with warnings turned on. As a consequence, the behavior of the program is undefined.

Undefined behavior being undefined, *nothing* can be said about the operation of the program.

P.S. The call to `execl()` is mighty strange. What do you think that `("%s", startLocation)` means which is different from plain `startLocation`? And arguments to `execl()` must be `char *` not `char`.

Comment: That's fixed it, thanks! I've said in a previous comment, I'm a student; I've only been using c for a couple of weeks and I'm not too experienced with programming in general. The `%s` descriptor was the only way I'd found to pass strings to functions without getting compilation errors. I know it's messy, but in terms of writing code for assignments my primary goal had been to just get the thing to run so i at least have a working program to submit. I usually go back and improve the readability after I know that I at least have something that runs to fall back on. Thanks again for the help